# How to animate paper tissue pulled out from a box?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

how to make the animation of pulling out a piece of paper tissue out of this container? I am a freshmen of animation, not sure which would be the right direction to dig into. Seems like it could be a combination of curve and rigid body? Thanks a lot!

In the picture, it is just a still model.

[image]

Aug.9th

Alittle update on this issue. I made a premature anime of pulling the paper tissue out.

Inspired by a toothpaste tutorial on youtube. Links: https://youtu.be/46DgMdxEhRQ

[There is my paper tissue anime.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOAmc.jpg)
Graph editing is confusing, comments are welcome.

Comment: is it supposed to be pulled by a hand? I guess you need to use Cloth physics and give your object a vertex group in order to use the cloth's Pinning option

Comment: No hands, but like you said it will be pulled out from a corner or the edge, pin will be definitely involved. Is there a feature paper tissue above this surface will show and below the surface will be hidden? Or, how to hid the rest of the tissue? Or just fold it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the final animation of the paper tissue flying out of the container.

[Paper tissue flying out the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh0lQ.jpg)

There is the set up.
[image]

Comment: oh nice, yes maybe it was more reasonable to achieve it this way, I tried to find a solution with physics but it seemed hard to achieve as it would have necessitate 2 points of tension, perhaps it was possible with one of the vertex modifier?

Comment: @moonboots vertex modifier? Please explain more. :D

Comment: with Vertex Weight Proximity modifier for example you can make the vertex group change through time, which maybe could have allowed to change the cloth pinning group? I'm not sure it is possible though

Comment: @moonboots it is a very interesting thought. I want to give it a try. or would you? :D

Comment: I did give a try but it gave me headache   ;)  actually if I had to do it I would have fake it like you've done, surface deform etc, I would have avoid physics because I'm not an expert enough, but it's an interesting challenge